# c# ILogger in class constructor throwing null exception

Tags: c#

I am working on .NET CORE 3.1 Azure Function application. My Azure Function class calls a  call services class. I am passing ILogger in contractor as part of dependency injection but getting null log reference.

Azure Function:

```cs
[FunctionName("myFunctionX")]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
       //code....
}
```

Service Class:

```cs
public class FAService : IFAService
{
    private ILogger log;

    public FAService(ILogger logger)
    {
        log = logger; // I am getting this null????
    }
```

Comment: `ILogger<FAService>`?

Answer (score 6):

Typically I've found that `ILogger` itself isn't resolved, but a *specific* `ILogger<T>` will be. So I would suggest changing your code to:

```cs
public class FAService : IFAService
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public FAService(ILogger<FAService> logger)
    {
        log = logger;
    }
```

(Note that it's fine to keep `log` as just `ILogger`.)

Comment: It can even be `readonly` ;-)

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL: Done, although I was basically just trying to make the minimal changes required.

Comment: Yes, I realized that afterward but I thought @K.Z could benefit from this comment. Thanks for the update